# Not able to get gpg keys on email while uploading lib to bintray.com

Tags: android, gnupg, aar, bintray

I am using [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) tutorial to upload my android lib to bintray.com

I am following below steps to upload lib:

> 1. gpg --gen-key
> 2. gpg --list-keys
> 3. gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys PUBLIC_KEY_ID
> 4. gpg -a    --export yourmail@email.com > public_key_sender.asc
> 5. gpg -a --export-secret-key yourmail@email.com > private_key_sender.asc

I have replaced PUBLIC_KEY_ID with my key id, same for email as well.

I am not getting why I am not receiving emails?.

Answer (score 2):

You should not expect to receive an e-mail at the address you used for the key. None of the steps you did there are supposed to result in any sort of e-mail confirmation being sent by anybody.

During `gpg --gen-key` you should have entered an e-mail address to associate with the key, and during the export you should have used the same e-mail address in order to tell GPG which key you wanted it to export for you. The e-mail just functions as a name for the key.

If all the GPG stuff completed without error, you should be able to go to http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/ and search the e-mail address you used, and have the key show up in the results list. If that works, you can continue with the next step of the tutorial:

> Open Bintray's Edit Profile page and click at GPG Signing. Fill in both Public Key and Private Key using content in public_key_sender.asc and private_key_sender.asc files exported in previous step respectively.